# What is the shell command used when running "Export" for JAR in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, maven, jar

I'd like to export my eclipse project as a JAR from the command line, but have only done this through the Eclipse UI with File -> Export -> Java -> JAR.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't necessarily execute a shell command.

Comment: Surely there must be some equivalent shell command for Eclipse's build/run/export, or am I that hopelessly naive?

Comment: There probably is.  But it isn't necessarily so.  Eclipse could be generating the JAR file itself, and it could be doing it in a way that is not 100% compatible with what you can generate with the Oracle `jar` command.

Comment: And if you are using Ant or Maven as the build tool (from within Eclipse), you also have to consider how >>they<< generate JAR files.

Comment: Anyway, the real answer if you want to generate a JAR file from the command line is to read the manual entry for the "jar" command, not to try to reverse engineer what Eclipse is doing.  (This in an "XY problem" ... http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 2):

The Java JDK provides the `jar` command: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jar.html

For more elaborate uses, you may be well advised to consider something like Apache Ant or Maven:

- https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/ - or, for what it sounds like you're probably really looking for here - https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/, which can create packages including dependencies.

Comment: Right. The jar command is key, but I have some libraries in my buildpath and I want to make sure that all the dependencies are packaged the exact same way as what Eclipse does.

Comment: @190290000RubleMan Is your Eclipse project configured as a Maven project?

Comment: It's not. Just Java :) This question is making me start to think that Eclipse may not use a shell command for build/export http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863181/is-it-possible-to-view-what-shell-commands-eclipse-is-making

Nonetheless, there must an equivalent command that I can use for build/export. There must!

Comment: This question might seem useful as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line

Comment: @190290000RubleMan 0 Correct, it doesn't use a shell command.  Per the link you provided, you could consider letting Eclipse generate an Ant script for you that you could use.  However, for best portability and a full feature set, I'd recommend using m2e to let Eclipse help you manage your Eclipse as a Maven project.  Then Maven's `pom.xml` owns your project configuration instead of Eclipse-specific `.project` and `.classpath` files - and then you can run any number of various build options from either the Maven command-line (using `mvn`), or from within Eclipse using m2e.

Comment: so what do I need to get started with m2e? I have it installed.

Comment: @190290000RubleMan You may like to start with https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/ .